# Apply function to several DataFrames by creating new DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, lambda

May be Someone can just help me to find the solution:

I have 100 dataframes. Each dataframe contains time / High_Price / Low_price
I would like to create new Dataframe, which contains Gains from each DataFrame.

Example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"high":[5,4,5,2], 
                      "low":[1,2,2,1]},
                      index=["2019-04-06","2019-04-07","2019-04-08","2019-04-09"])

df100 = pd.DataFrame({"high":[7,5,6,7], 
                      "low":[1,2,3,4]},
                      index=["2019-04-06","2019-04-07","2019-04-08","2019-04-09"])
```

Functions:

```
def myfunc(data, amount):
    data= data.loc[(data!=0).any(1)]
    profit = (amount/data.iloc[0]['low']) * data.iloc[-1]['high']
    return profit
```

Output should be:

```
output= pd.DataFrame({"Gain":[1,6]},
                      index=["df1","df100"])
```

How can I apply function to 100 DataFrames and get from them only Gains by creating the Dataframe, where we see the name of DataFrame and the Gain for this DataFrame?

Comment: Where does `amount` come from when calling the function? Is it the same for all dfs?

Comment: `amount` always the same for all DataFrames, can be just 1.

Answer (score 0):

Put your dataframes in a list and access them by integer index. Having variables named `df1` to `df100` is bad programming style because a) the dataframes belong together, so put them in a collection (e.g. list) and b) you cannot get "the" name of an object from its value, leading to complications such as the one you are facing now.

So let `dfs` be your list of 100 dataframes, starting at index 0.

Use

```
amount = ... # the value you want to use
output = pd.DataFrame([myfunc(df, amount) for df in dfs], columns=['Gain'])
```

The index of `output` now corresponds to the index of `dfs`, starting at 0. There's no reason to rename it to `'df1'` ... `'df100'`, you gain no information and the output becomes harder to handle.

---

In case of arbitrary dataframe names, use a dictionary that maps name to df. Let's call it `dfs` again. Then use

```
amount = ... # the value you want to use
output = pd.DataFrame([myfunc(df, amount) for df in dfs.values()], columns=['Gain'], index=dfs.keys()])
```

I'm assuming `myfunc` is correct, I did not debug it.

Comment: I have different names for DFs, here it was just an example. Tried to put DFs to a list, then apply the code: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'apply' ... It seems now I have problems with .iloc or datatype.

Comment: @Val.Val in that case use a dictionary that maps df-names to the dfs. I did not debug your function.